# Short film or movie about kids abducted by aliens who crave anchovies

Tags: story-identification, movie, short-film

I am trying to find the name of this short film or movie that I vaguely remember from my youth (the 1980s). All I remember is kids in a car, them getting abducted, and something about the aliens who abducted them loving anchovy pizza.

Comment: Cartoon or live-action?

Comment: Being forced to crave anchovies sounds more like something out of a horror movie, not sci-fi. Or do you mean the aliens crave anchovies?

Comment: And suddenly Futurama makes more sense...

Answer (score 4):

UFO Kidnapped! by Nickelodeon in 1983.  It featured the cast of [*You Can't Do That on Television*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_Can%27t_Do_That_on_Television), a high school parody/comedy series.  [YouTube videos start here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfxQdwWZdQU)

The story has several children and a few adults being abducted by aliens in a classical silver saucer.  The aliens liked anchovies on pizza, laughed often at the humans' ignorance about aliens and outer space, and took them in their spacecraft through a portal in the Sun to another star system.  UFO Kidnapped! was a pilot show that was never picked up by Nickelodeon.  *You Can't Do That on Television* was actually produced in Canada.